# Selecting correct parameters for time series classification

Tags: time-series, classification, k-means, lda, self-organizing-maps

I'm facing a big challenge with a data source in my research. Basically I have six types of events that is registered for post processing. This events are related to a kind of ion used on the process and the position where the event occurs on the device. Image 1 shows an average curve for each type of even.

**Image 1**

[image: Image 1 Average curves]

My objective is classify the type of ion looking for this curve, to study the curve I'm using  four parameters extracted from each curve: `peak value [max value]`,`middle length[red line]`, `Rising time[green]` and `Base length [ blue]`, as show in Image 2.

**Image 2**

[image: Features extracted]

I'm using two types of algorithms to try classify the curves, `K-means` and `LDA`, but the results at this moment is not clear, I don't have good clusters and classifiers, also I run a `SOM` algorithm and a got a better results, but not very statisfactory. I believe that the parameters are not good selection. How can I have a good  indicative of good parameters? How can I choose the right parameters to my classifiers? There is good practices to use in this case?

Comment: You haven't really said why you are using those four parameters for curve fitting. Are they predefined outputs of the device? Basically you have four constraints, so it's effectively a third order polynomial, right? But by my eyeball, it seems like a second order polynomial would be enough, for the small dataset you showed at least.

Comment: @TomAnderson, I'm trying to obtain a model to classify this events. My first approach was extract these parameters and apply the values to algorithms of clustering trying to find some correlation between this parameters and the type of event. My problem now is, how can I measure the quality of these parameters for a classification process?

Answer (score 0):

One way to proceed is to devise an experiment that compares two things. For example, you wonder if the parameters are good. Try a different set of four parameters, such as the amplitude at four fixed time intervals (e.g. the amplitude at 20ms, 30ms, 40ms and 50ms). When you compare the original set of parameters to the new set, you will have results that show one way was better than the other for those the test conditions. Maybe one set provides more relevant information that the other for the classification task.

This assumes that you have some data with known classifications. It's best to use a different training set separate from the test set.

Or if your experiment is simply kmeans vs LDA, which one works better? How much better? Do you know why?

At the end of this, you will have a lot of experiments, each that compares two things. It might help you describe your findings.